# Creating a table/grid with a frozen columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a grid in WPF bound to a ObservableCollection(MVVM). I have some monthly information so the first columns refer to a task and then I have one column per day. For these reason it's very important to frozen first columns and then user may scroll horizontally to see all days information. I need vertical scroll working too.

This question is similar to that [Creating a table/grid with a frozen column and frozen headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586753/creating-a-table-grid-with-a-frozen-column-and-frozen-headers) but I don't have any clue on how to do it with C#/WPF. Any ideas? I have only thought about using two grids but I don't know if its possible to sync vertical scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to freeze columns DataGrid have property called as FrozenColumnCount

Please see link for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: I'm using a DevXpress GridControl and I can't find this property there. Anyway, thanks for the clue. I should ask there for this property.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in DevXpress GridControl setting Fixed property of the desired GridColumn to true.