# Table view look and usability enhancement

Tags: java, android, tableview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have an activity, in which I have created a populated a table view with XML data parsed. The table view looks the way I want it and functionally it is also correct, but I want to enhance the vertical scrolling feature of the table view.

**The Sr.No. column is vertically scrollable, but horizontally fixed. This is as per my requirement, hence no change is required!**

Screen shot:

[image: Sr.No. table horizontally fixed]

**The whole table is vertically scrollable, including the serial no column. This is also as per my requirement, hence no change is required!**

Screen shot:

[image: whole table vertical scroll]

**My requirement is that, the header of the tables will remain vertically fixed while scrolling, such that the user will be able to see the the column names even if he scrolls down to the bottom of the table.**

The screen shot of the desired output:

[image: table header vertically fixed]

Source code of activity:

```
public class ReportListActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout srno_table;
    TableRow srno_report_tr_data;

    TableLayout report_table;
    TableRow report_tr_data;

  //variables to send post request
    String reportList_responseBody;
    String reportList_responseCode;


    //variables to parse xml
    String report_list_xmlContent;

 // XML node keys of Exam Details
    static final String KEY_SET = "Set"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_EXAMSETID = "ExamSetId";
    static final String KEY_SETID = "SetId";
    static final String KEY_SETNAME = "SetName";
    static final String KEY_FULLMARKS = "FullMarks";
    static final String KEY_RIGHTMARKS = "RightMarks";
    static final String KEY_WRONGMARKS = "WrongMarks";
    static final String KEY_LEFTMARKS = "LeftMarks";
    static final String KEY_OBTAINMARKS = "ObtainMarks";
    static final String KEY_STUDENTRANK = "StudentRank";
    static final String KEY_EXAMDATE = "ExamDate";

    //Progressbar object
            ProgressDialog progress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report_list);
        //setting icon to title bar
        getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.ic_launcher);

      //starting the progress bar
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait","Getting report list", true);

        //===============For marquee===================================

            TextView marqueeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marquee_textView);
            marqueeTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getFromPreference("marquee_Html_content")));
            marqueeTextView.setSelected(true);
            //===============For marquee===================================

        //sending post request to download data
        reportList_isOnline();

        srno_table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.srno_table);

        //---------------Serial no Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow srno_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        srno_tr_head.setId(10);
        srno_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        srno_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView label_sr_no = new TextView(this);
        label_sr_no.setId(20);
        label_sr_no.setText("S.No.");
        label_sr_no.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_sr_no.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        srno_tr_head.addView(label_sr_no);// add the column to the table row here
        label_sr_no.setTextSize(15);    



        srno_table.addView(srno_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      //---------------Serial no Table Header-----------------------------------------------

        report_table=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.report_table);

        //---------------report Table Header-----------------------------------------------
        TableRow report_tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        report_tr_head.setId(10);
        report_tr_head.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_header);
        report_tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        TextView label_test_name = new TextView(this);
        label_test_name.setId(20);
        label_test_name.setText("Test Name");
        label_test_name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        label_test_name.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        report_tr_head.addView(label_test_name);// add the column to the table row here
        label_test_name.setTextSize(15);    

        TextView label_test_date = new TextView(this);
        label_test_date.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_test_date.setText("Date"); // set the text for the header 
        label_test_date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_test_date.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_test_date); // add the column to the table row here
        label_test_date.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_ro = new TextView(this);
        label_ro.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_ro.setText("R.O."); // set the text for the header 
        label_ro.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_ro.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_ro); // add the column to the table row here
        label_ro.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_wo = new TextView(this);
        label_wo.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_wo.setText("W.O."); // set the text for the header 
        label_wo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_wo.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_wo); // add the column to the table row here
        label_wo.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_lo = new TextView(this);
        label_lo.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_lo.setText("L.O."); // set the text for the header 
        label_lo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_lo.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_lo); // add the column to the table row here
        label_lo.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_max = new TextView(this);
        label_max.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_max.setText("Max."); // set the text for the header 
        label_max.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_max.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_max); // add the column to the table row here
        label_max.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_tm = new TextView(this);
        label_tm.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_tm.setText("T.M."); // set the text for the header 
        label_tm.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_tm.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_tm); // add the column to the table row here
        label_tm.setTextSize(15);

        TextView label_rank = new TextView(this);
        label_rank.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_rank.setText("Rank"); // set the text for the header 
        label_rank.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // set the color
        label_rank.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
        report_tr_head.addView(label_rank); // add the column to the table row here
        label_rank.setTextSize(15);


        report_table.addView(report_tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      //---------------Serial no Table Header-----------------------------------------------




    }
    //onclick device back button
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do something on back.

        Intent intent = new Intent(ReportListActivity.this, TakeTestActivity.class);
        finish();
        ReportListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }


  //method to show toast message
        public void makeAToast(String str) {
            //yet to implement
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }


    //check connection
        public boolean reportList_isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {



                 //sending request for exam name list
                new MyAsyncTask_download_report_list().execute(getFromPreference("student_code"),getFromPreference("reportExamType"));



                return true;
            }

          //alert box to show internet connection error
            AlertDialog.Builder Internet_Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportListActivity.this);
            // set title
            Internet_Alert.setCancelable(false);
            Internet_Alert.setTitle("Attention!");
            Internet_Alert.setMessage("This application requires internet connectivity, no internet connection detected");
            Internet_Alert.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    onQuitPressed(); 
                }
            });

            Internet_Alert.create().show();
            return false;
        }

    //to remove application from task manager
        public void onQuitPressed() {

            int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        }

         //saving A VALUE in preference variable
        public void saveInPreference(String name, String content)
        {
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
             editor.putString(name,content);
             editor.commit();
        }

        //getting content from preferences
        public String getFromPreference(String variable_name)
        {
            String preference_return;
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            preference_return = preferences.getString(variable_name,"");

            return preference_return;
        }

        //===================================================================================================================================
        //sending student code and exam type to server to report list
        //===================================================================================================================================
        private class MyAsyncTask_download_report_list extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{


            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                postData(params[0],params[1]);
                return null;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){




                report_list_xmlContent=reportList_responseBody;
                parse_ReportList();

            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){

            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void postData(String student_code, String exam_type) {

                //to handle connection timeout
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);

                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);


                // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ReportListActivity.this);
                final String url_first = preferences.getString("URLFirstPart","");
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url_first+"StudentReport");

                try {
                    // Data that I am sending
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StudentCode", student_code));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ExamType", exam_type));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    try 
                    {
                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                  //getting response body and code from the server
                    reportList_responseCode=""+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    reportList_responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    } 
                    catch (SocketTimeoutException ex)
                    {
                       //showing alert in case of connection timeout
                       AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ReportListActivity.this).create();

                       // Setting Dialog Title
                       alertDialog.setTitle("Please Note");

                      // Setting Dialog Message
                      alertDialog.setMessage("Connection problem, please try later!");

                      // Setting OK Button
                      alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
                        dialog.cancel();
                        }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
                    }

                    Log.d("Report list response body: ", reportList_responseBody);
                    Log.d("Report list response code: ", reportList_responseCode);
                }
                catch (Throwable t ) {
                    //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),""+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("Error Time of Login",t+"");
                }
            }
        }
        //===================================================================================================================================
        //END sending student code and exam type to server to report list
        //===================================================================================================================================

        // function to populate report list from xml
        void parse_ReportList()
        {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(report_list_xmlContent); // getting DOM element

            //list object to populate spinner
            //List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();



            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SET);
            // looping through all item nodes <item>
            for ( int i = 0; i < nl.getLength();i++) {

                //----------------Serial no table body------------------------------------------
                 srno_report_tr_data = new TableRow(this);
                    srno_report_tr_data.setId(10);
                    srno_report_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                    srno_report_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                    final TextView sr_no = new TextView(this);
                    sr_no.setId(20);
                    sr_no.setText(""+(i+1));
                    sr_no.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    sr_no.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    sr_no.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    sr_no.setTextSize(12);
                    srno_report_tr_data.addView(sr_no);// add the column to the table row here





                    srno_table.addView(srno_report_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  //----------------Serial no table body------------------------------------------

        //----------------Report table body------------------------------------------       

                report_tr_data=new TableRow(this);
                report_tr_data.setId(10);
                report_tr_data.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.grey_list_bg);
                report_tr_data.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                // creating new HashMap
                //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


                   //Exam name
                    final TextView test_name = new TextView(this);
                    test_name.setId(20);
                    test_name.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_SETNAME));
                    test_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    test_name.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
                    test_name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    test_name.setTextSize(12);
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_name);// add the column to the table row here


                    //Exam date
                    final TextView test_date = new TextView(this);
                    test_date.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                    test_date.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMDATE)); // set the text for the header 
                    test_date.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                    test_date.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                    test_date.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    test_date.setTextSize(12);
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_date); // add the column to the table row here



                    //R.O.
                    final TextView test_ro = new TextView(this);
                    test_ro.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                    test_ro.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_RIGHTMARKS)); // set the text for the header 
                    test_ro.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                    test_ro.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                    test_ro.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    test_ro.setTextSize(12);
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_ro); // add the column to the table row here



                   //W.O.
                    final TextView test_wo = new TextView(this);
                    test_wo.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                    test_wo.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_WRONGMARKS)); // set the text for the header 
                    test_wo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                    test_wo.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                    test_wo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    test_wo.setTextSize(12);
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_wo); // add the column to the table row here


                //L.O.
                    final TextView test_lo = new TextView(this);
                    test_lo.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                    test_lo.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_LEFTMARKS)); // set the text for the header 
                    test_lo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                    test_lo.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                    test_lo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    test_lo.setTextSize(12);
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_lo); // add the column to the table row here  


                //MAX       
                final TextView test_max = new TextView(this);
                test_max.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                test_max.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_FULLMARKS)); // set the text for the header 
                test_max.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                test_max.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                test_max.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                test_max.setTextSize(12);
                report_tr_data.addView(test_max); // add the column to the table row here


                //TM
                final TextView test_tm = new TextView(this);
                test_tm.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                test_tm.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_OBTAINMARKS)); // set the text for the header 
                test_tm.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                test_tm.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                test_tm.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                test_tm.setTextSize(12);
                report_tr_data.addView(test_tm); // add the column to the table row here


                //RANK
                final TextView test_rank = new TextView(this);
                test_rank.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                test_rank.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_STUDENTRANK)); // set the text for the header 
                test_rank.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                test_rank.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                test_rank.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                test_rank.setTextSize(12);
                report_tr_data.addView(test_rank); // add the column to the table row here

                //EXAM SET ID
                  final TextView test_exam_set = new TextView(this);
                    test_exam_set.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                    test_exam_set.setText(parser.getValue(e, KEY_EXAMSETID)); // set the text for the header
                    test_exam_set.setTextSize((float) 0.01);
                    test_exam_set.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // set the color
                    test_exam_set.setPadding(5,5,5,5); // set the padding (if required)
                    report_tr_data.addView(test_exam_set); // add the column to the table row here



                report_table.addView(report_tr_data, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    //----------------------On click table row---------------------------------------

                report_tr_data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                        saveInPreference("showReportTab", "ScoreCard");
                        saveInPreference("reportExamName", test_name.getText().toString());
                        saveInPreference("reportExamSet", test_exam_set.getText().toString());
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ReportListActivity.this, ReportDetailsActivity.class);
                        finish();
                        ReportListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                //----------------------On click table row---------------------------------------



                //----------------Report table body------------------------------------------   


                //deactivating progress bar
                progress.dismiss();

            }


        }
}
```

The layout file is [here](http://pastie.org/7696094)

**P.S.: Every row is clickable except the header**

Comment: When you say "every row is clickable except the header", what do you mean?

I saw your comment on my post a few hours ago and will do my best to help. Would it be useful if I packaged up my working solution and put it up somewhere?

Comment: @Kevek it will be very good if you can post the working solution as a sample project somewhere. Every row is clickable means, there is a click event associated to every row, onclick each row a particular event will be fired. If you look into the activity class which I have posted, you will get some idea.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I also have issues with scrolling in the grid view, can you please help me out with my issue? Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440471/android-grid-view-concomitant-scrolling-delay